# How can I include and use html2canvas in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to use this `https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas`  but getting error after including its cdn like

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript" xml="space"></script>
```

When I use it like

```
download : function() {
        html2canvas($("#result-box"), {
          scale: 2,
        onrendered: function(canvas) {

             var a = document.createElement('a');
             window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg"));
             a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg").replace("image/jpg", "image/octet-stream");
             a.download = 'lash-prescription.jpg';
             a.click();


     }
        });
    }
```

it says

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: html2canvas is not defined
    at Object.download (my.js:269)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you try to call function from js library when it doesn't loaded.
Try to wrap your function in:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  Your function here
});
```

Comment: I tried . but  I read some where I need to put some  require(['jquery'], function ($) { }   like this type of representation ?